# Unexpected Syntax Error: Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

now ,this is _search_box.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Buscarse" %>
    <%= end %>
```

and this is search.thml.erb

```
   <% render :partial => "search_box" %>
   <% if @boxes %>
   <p>Your search "<%= params[:q] %>" produced
   <%= pluralize @boxes.size, "result" %>:</p>
   <%= render(:partial => "boxes") %>
   <% end %>
```

and this is what i get

```
    syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.to_s
```

Comment: you forgot to add "do" keyword in form_tag `<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do%>`

Comment: I just added "do" but still shows this error message syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.to_s

Answer (score 2):

You've got error in your `_search_box` partial:

```
 <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %> # and here too
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Buscarse" %>
    <% end %>   # remove = here
```

And you've missed `do` also.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, you were missing `do` in the `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %>
2<%= text_field_tag :q %>
3<%= submit_tag "Buscarse" %>
4<% end %>

5<%= render :partial => "search_box" %>
```

Line 1. you have missed `do`

Line 4. just `<% end %>`

Line 5. `<% render :partial => "search_box" %>` to `<%= render :partial => "search_box" %>`

Comment: Now, doesn't throws any error but the search doesn't find anything